# iOS 9 "Save PDF to iBooks" with HTML

Tags: html, ios, pdf

`iOS 9` has a new built-in `UIActivity` of `UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks`. It's in the default list of activities in the UI and in header file but I've not been able to find any API documentation for it (yet).

It appears that `UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks` will create a PDF in iBooks just fine if you include UIImages in your `UIActivityViewController` items or return them in your `UIActivityItemProvider`.

However I'd like to create a `PDF` with an HTML page containing text and images like Safari does. But I can't seem to find a way to pass the HTML to `UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks` in an acceptable way.

I've tried passing the HTML as a String, `NSData` and `NSURL` of a file. I've also tried returning an UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter which works fine for printing but not for `UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks`.

Providing an HTML string or the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter both result in the following errors:

```
2015-09-08 11:35:46.392 MyApp[4599:1492484] ERROR: attempting to save to URL with no printing source (formatter/renderer) set
2015-09-08 11:35:46.393 MyApp[4599:1492484] FAILED! due to error in domain UIPrintErrorDomain with error code 4
```

*Has anyone gotten this working?*

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the html to pdf before saving it to ibooks.